# Загрузка картинок с фронтенд в CS-CART

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

Собственно следующая проблема, надо расширить модуль отзывов (которые о сайте в целом, не отзывы о товарах), добавить пару полей и возможность ещё загрузить фото. Если в административной панели получилось реализовать с помощью вот этой инструкции: https://www.cs-cart.ru/docs/4.11.x/developer_guide/core/images_subsystem.html#id2 По крайней мере добавление отзыва, с обновлением данных тоже не всё гладко, картинка не обновляется в случае замены, но это уже другой вопрос, то на фронтенде по понятным причинам безопасности такой вариант не работает (в связи с отсутствием файла common/attach_images.tpl).
На официальном форуме сказали использовать common/fileuploader.tpl он для фронтенда есть, но вот только пояснения никто не дал. Вообще не могу понять, как через него можно в image_pair создаваемого объекта добавить изображение.
Может кто сталкивался со схожей задачей?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем путем проб и ошибок, а так же подсказкам на официальном форуме CS-CART решение нашёл.
Делается так:

1. Создаём модуль.
2. Содержимое init.php

```php
<?php

if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

fn_register_hooks(
    'add_discussion_post_post'
);
```

3. Содержимое func.php

```php
<?php

if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

function fn_<название вашего модуля>_add_discussion_post_post(&$post_data, $send_notifications) {
    fn_attach_image_pairs('discussion_image', 'discussion', $post_data['post_id']);
}
```

4. В файле design/themes/<название вашей темы>/templates/addons/discussion/views/discussion/components/new_post.tpl (в случае если посадка на основе именно темы, а не посадка через модуль модификации темы. При модуле модификации используем хуки для расширения темы) добавляем строку в нужном месте формы (где надо отобразить загрузку файла)

```
{include file="design/backend/templates/common/attach_images.tpl" image_name="discussion_image" image_object_type="discussion" image_object_id=$obj_id image_pair=$obj.main_pair image_type="M" no_detailed=true hide_titles=true hide_alt=true}
```

5. В файле design/themes/<название вашей темы>/templates/addons/discussion/views/discussion/components/new_post.tpl в теге form добавляем аттрибут enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

Есть модулек которые это делает - https://forum.cs-cart.ru/t/modul-ot-retailfactory-ru-otzyvy-s-fotografiyami-i-lajkami/11093
Вообще в целом, хук на фронте, который выводит поле для выбора фоток, в форме отзывов. И второй хук, который при сохранении отзыва дергается, в нем сохраняет правильно фотки, в поля в бд, которые ваш модуль, в своей схеме должен создавать.
В доках описано всё это. Можно искать похожие модули, и смотреть как и что они делают, и разбираться. Искать модули, можно бесплатные, которые расширяют отзывы, и по аналогии искать нужные хуки в модуле discusion - "hook"

Comment: Мне не совсем такое решение нужно, я же написал, отзывы на сайт (компанию), и фото для другого совсем. Я решение сегодня нашёл, не знаю, на сколько верное (https://forum.cs-cart.ru/t/kak-dobavit-pole-zagruzki-izobrazhenij-v-modul-chtoby-ono-rabotalo/14070/12) Сообщество PHP вообще скудное, толком никто помочь не хочет, ладно бы было руководство от разработчиков толковое, где было бы всё описано, и можно было бы носом тыкнуть. Так нет, и документации нет, так ещё и все "гуру" зазвездились!!! Не зря давно ушёл на python :-)

Comment: Ну и оставались бы на Питоне.

Comment: Желаемое не всегда действительное!!!